# Regular expression to pull image name

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this

```
image/jpeg; name="3.jpg"
```

i want to pull out `3.jpg` through php regular expression. i am using

```
$test='image/jpeg; name="3.jpg"';

preg_match('/^.*image\/(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|GIF|PNG|JPG|JPEG).*(name=(.+))?$/',$test, $matches);
```

but it isn't pulling out the name. Can you please guide me where am i doing wrong

Comment: What's the problem? what is the output you got?

Comment: this is the output Array ( [0] => image/jpeg; name="3.jpg" [1] => jpeg )  but i need 3.jpg in array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
.*(name=(.+))?$
```

First, `.*` matches everything until the end of the string.

Then, `(name=(.+))?` can't match anything, but since it's optional, that's OK. So the match is successful, but nothing has been captured.

```
/^.*image\/(?:GIF|PNG|JPG|JPEG).*?(?:name=(.+))?$/i
```

would help in this case, making the `.*?` match as few characters as possible. (Also, unless you're being case-sensitive with `image` and `name`, you can shorten the regex with the `/i` modifier.)

If you only need the file name, you can make the other groups non-capturing (`(?:...)`), too.

Comment: Excellent.. but since i needed only 3.jpg i added /^.*image\/(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|GIF|PNG|JPG|JPEG).*?(name="(.+)")?$/

Comment: Look at version history of the question the OP was using `/` as a delimiter and not escaping the `/` in `image/`. @Rohit Jain made this edit then you both left comments saying my assertion was wrong?